# C# - Traversing Nodes of a Tree and Identify level

Tags: c#, loops, recursion, tree

I have an application that allows a user to select items from a tree structure that are then passed to a method that builds a report. The item is the smallest level of granularity and contains an id value. I need to produce an enumerable object that can be used to produce both summery level reports and individual item reports. For example, the picture bellow shows the tree and the desire report structure. [image]

What I need is to be able to identify or flag items that need to be printed individually. In other words if item is not found in any child groups then mark it as needs to print individual. This is important because it is possible for the item to exist in more than one grouping.  How can I parse through the tree and check if the item exists in a child node?

The Item and ItemSet(groups) classes are as follows:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
    public int Property3 { get; set; }
    public int Property4 { get; set; }
}

public class ItemSet
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    //.
    //.
    //.
    //.
    public List<ItemSet> ItemSets { get; set; }



}
```

Notice that an itemset can contain other item sets. Also, the list of Items includes all items including item in children. I need a mechanism to check for if the item exists at that level alone.

**UPDATE**

To further clarify, I have added summarized class diagrams to illustrate the relationships/composition of Items, ItemSets, and the application as a whole.This is a legacy code base so and so i do not have much flexibility and must make do with most of what is in existence. When `getAllItems()` is called on a partiular set, it returns all of its decedents, even if it is an item the belongs to a nested set. I need to be able to determine if it is a direct decedent or a child of a sub set.

[image]

Comment: You seem to be mixing up a lot of different terms in your question that makes it really hard to follow. What is a well and how does relate to an `Item`? What is an `ItemSet` and how does it relate to a Group? What do you consider a child node and how does that relate to a well or an `Item` or a group or an `ItemSet`?

Comment: Sorry a well is an Item. Items exist in an ItemSet which is also what I am calling a group or node in the tree. I will clarify.

Comment: Do you show any Items in your example that need to be flagged? How do you know they exist?

Comment: I will update post to clarify what im dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var item in itemSet.getAllItems())
{
  if (item.Parent == itemSet)
  {
    // Is child of itemSet
  }
  else
  {
    // Is descendant of nested itemSet
  }
}
```